# Lint warning with ButterKnife usage

Tags: gradle, lint, butterknife

We're started using ButterKnife and I found two new lint warning in Jenkins CI:

```
Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.lang.model.util. Referenced from butterknife.internal.Listener
```

Are there way to disable lint checks for dependency classes? Is this good practice to check dependencies as well?